# Get first or most repeated value from a group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ugly table with codes and names from a source I can't control, which is like this one (OriginalTable):

```
Code    | Name
--------------------
001-001 | Name1_a
001-002 | Name1_a
001-002 | Name1_b
001-003 | Name1_a
002-001 | Name2_a
002-001 | Name2_b
002-002 | Name2_a
003-001 | Name3
...
```

The problem is that I need an unique name for the first 3 digits of each code (SmallCode), like in the following table:

```
Id  | Code  | Name
--------------------
1   | 001   | NameX
2   | 002   | NameY
3   | 003   | NameZ
```

The criteria I want use for choosing a name is that it should be the most repeated name or the first one in each SmallCode.
For example NameX is the most repeated name on of all codes starting with 001 or the first one (Name1_a in both cases). Same with NameY for 002 and NameZ for 003.

Right now I was using this query:

```
select Substring(Code,1,3) as SmallCode, Code, Name
into #tmpCode
from OriginalTable

select SmallCode, Min(Code) as Code
into #tmpReducedCode
from #tmpCode
group by SmallCode

insert into ResultTable (Code, Name)
select a.SmallCode, a.Name
from #tmpCode a
    inner join #tmpReducedCode b
        on a.Code = b.Code
```

But this is my result, which is wrong because there are 2 different names for code 002-001 (Name2_a, Name2_b)

```
1   | 001   | Name1_a
2   | 002   | Name2_a
3   | 002   | Name2_b
4   | 003   | Name3
```

So the question is: How can I separate OriginalTable into those 2 tables choosing the most repeated or first appearing name for each small code?

Comment: Damned hard to see what's wrong, when the data you are saying is wrong doesn't feature in the example data you provided...

Comment: You're right, I changed it. Thanks for commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first table:

```
select Substring(Code,1,3) as SmallCode, Code, Name
into #tmpCode
from OriginalTable

select SmallCode, Name
into #tmpReducedCode
from (
    select SmallCode, Name, row_number() over (partition by SmallCode order by Total desc) rn
    from (
        select SmallCode, Name, count(*) Total
        from #tmpCode
        group by SmallCode, Name) x) y
where rn=1;

select distinct a.SmallCode, b.Name
from #tmpCode a
    inner join #tmpReducedCode b
        on left(a.Code,3) = b.SmallCode
```

Comment: Tested it and worked as I wanted. Can you explain me what is `row_number() over partition...`?

Comment: In short, it uniquely and sequentially numbers rows in the output, going 1,2,3 etc, but restarting from 1 for each `partition`. In this case, for each different SmallCode, it restarts numbering at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Run subquery for each code:

```
select distinct substring(Code,1,3) as "Code", 
    (select top 1 Name
    from OrginalTable tab2
    where substring(tab2.Code,1,3)=substring(tab1.Code,1,3)
    group by substring(Code,1,3), Name 
    order by count(Name) desc) as "Name"
from OrginalTable tab1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is with window functions:

```
select cast(LEFT(code, 3) as int) as id,
       RIGHT(code, 3) as code,
       name
from (select cn.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by code order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from (select code, name, COUNT(*) as cnt
            from OriginalTable ot
            group by code, name
           ) cn
     ) cn
where seqnum = 1
```

This assumes you are using SQL Server 2005 or a more recent version.